# How to get Firebase Storage image as base64?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am use Node.js Firebase Cloud Function but need get image I have store in Firebase Cloud Function as base64 so I can send to Google Cloud vision API which require base64.

How to do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know firebase at all, but I'm guessing it's just an API enpoint you call to get an image. If so, you can download the image as an `arraybuffer` and then change its format:

```
const imgUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ianare/exif-samples/master/jpg/Canon_40D.jpg'

const getBase64Img = async () => {
  const image = await axios.get(imgUrl, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
  
  return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But how to store this in local storage with fs?

Comment: Are you in node or in browser? Node doesn't have local storage, but if you want to cache the base64 string you can use lru-cache for example.